# Accounting for complex survey design for structural equation modeling

Tags: sas, structural-equation-modeling, survey-weights

I am using proc calis procedure in SAS to perform structural equation modeling (SEM). I have a nationally representative survey data with person-level weights, strata and cluster variables. However, I am unable to incorporate these variables in my analysis. I looked for literature, read SAS documentation and papers, and also asked on SAS community, but could not find anything relevant. Is it not possible to account for the survey design in SEM in SAS? Also, a bigger picture question, is it always required to account for the survey design when doing analyses such as Confirmatory Factor Analysis or SEM?

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible in SAS. You can do it with R using the surveylavaan package, or in Mplus.